# yum remove is hang + optional for time out

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, rpm

when I try to remove this rpm ( from my bash script )

```
 yum remove graphite-web-0.9.15-1.el7.noarch >/dev/null 2>&1
```

we noticed from the logs that yum is hang for a long time

as workaround can we set yum with time out ( as timeout of 10 min ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU Coreutils `timeout`, you could do:

```
timeout 10m yum remove graphite-web-0.9.15-1.el7.noarch
```

You can check the exit status to see if the command succeeded or timed out. An exit status of '124' indicates that the `yum` command timed out.

See the manual for more details: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html

While that solves the immediate problem, I would still advise you to check why the `yum` command takes so long. `yum` has a `--verbose` option that could help. `strace` can help you take a deeper look.